Are infirm people who can’t work obligated to give tzedakah
According to Halacha, are infirm people who can not work due to age, injury, illness etc. obligated to donate tzedakah or no? In this scenario, they are still mentally competent, although they  can’t work for an income because of their predicament.

Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah siman 248 siff 1 reads:

כל אדם חייב ליתן צדקה אפילו עני המתפרנס מן הצדקה חייב ליתן ממה שיתנו לו

So the answer is yes.
